# Enable autocomplete when using Hosted Payment Fields

Tags: bluesnap

I'm wondering if it's possible to enable autocomplete of a credit card stored in the browser, for example using simple html, the browser shows option to autocomplete stored credit card details.

```
<form method="post" id="usrForm">
  <h4>Do not use a real card</h4>
  <label for="nameoncard">Name on Card</label>
  <input type="text" id="nameoncard" name="nameoncard" autocomplete="cc-name">
  <label for="ccnumber">Credit Card Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="ccnumber" name="ccnumber" autocomplete="cc-number">
  <label for="cc-exp-month">Expiration Month</label>
  <input type="number" id="cc-exp-month" name="cc-exp-month" autocomplete="cc-exp-month">
  <label for="cc-exp-year">Expiration Year</label>
  <input type="number" id="cc-exp-year" name="cc-exp-year" autocomplete="cc-exp-year">
  <label for="cvv2">CVV</label>
  <input type="text" id="cvv2" name="cvv2" autocomplete="cc-csc">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

We are using a form with Hosted payment fields, something like that:

```
<div class="panel panel-default bootstrap-basic">
  <form class="panel-body" action="your-form-handling-page" method="POST" id="checkout-form" onsubmit="return do_when_clicking_submit_button()">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="cardholder-name">Name on Card</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cardholder-name" placeholder="Full Name">
          <span class="helper-text"></span>
       </div>
       <!--Hosted Field for CC number-->
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="form-control" id="card-number" data-bluesnap="ccn"></div>
            <div id="card-logo" class="input-group-addon"><img src="https://files.readme.io/d1a25b4-generic-card.png" height="20px"></div>
         </div>
         <span class="helper-text" id="card-help"></span>
       </div>
             <!--Hosted Field for CC EXP-->
       <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
          <label for="exp-date">Exp. Date</label>
          <div class="form-control" id="exp-date" data-bluesnap="exp"></div>
          <span class="helper-text"></span>
       </div>
            <!--Hosted Field for CC CVV-->
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
         <label for="cvv">Security Code</label>
         <div class="form-control" id="cvv" data-bluesnap="cvv"></div>
         <span class="helper-text"></span>
      </div>
    </div>  

        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" type="submit" id="submit-button">Pay Now</button>

        </form>

</div>

<!--BlueSnap Hosted Payment Fields JavaScript file-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/hosted-payment-fields/v1.0/bluesnap.hpf.mini.js"></script>
```

It would be awesome if there would be a way so that browsers suggests autocomplete.

Am I missing something obvious here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I work for BlueSnap. Unfortunately the Hosted fields themselves have autocomplete disabled so this will not work no matter what you add to the divs in your client code (if you inspect the field you will see autocomplete="off") . I have opened a bug in our system to support this since I can see why it's an important feature to have. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Looking forward to this! Thanks!